How to "rebase" one transform to another, to prevent multiple roots in the transform tree?
I have a sensor that publishes the absolute pose of a leaf link as nav_msgs.msg.Odometry  (which would be world -> head in my transform tree). This leaf link is connected to the base link via a revolute joint, that can rotate around one axis (base_link -> head). In order to not end up with multiple roots in the tf tree, I tried to set up an intermediate node, that transforms the pose of head in the global frame to the base link frame, and publish this pose as my actual absolute pose (world -> base_link), but it did not actually work. The rotation of the head is not correctly cancelled out, and the whole robot seems to be spinning around when the head rotates.
This is the code of my attempt so far:
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.time import Duration

from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

from tf2_ros.buffer import Buffer as TfBuffer
from tf2_ros.transform_listener import TransformListener
from tf2_ros import TransformException
from tf2_geometry_msgs import PoseWithCovarianceStamped

import tf_transformations

class NodeImpl(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('odometry_rebase_node')
        self.input_child_frame_override = "head"
        self.output_child_frame = "base_link"
        self.tf_buffer = TfBuffer()
        self.tf_listener = TransformListener(self.tf_buffer, self)
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(
            Odometry, 'odometry_out', 1)
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            Odometry, 'odometry_in', self.callback, 1)

    def callback(self, msg):
        msg = self.transform_to_target(msg)
        if msg is not None:
            self.publisher_.publish(msg)

    def transform_to_target(self, msg):
        target_frame = self.output_child_frame
        original_frame = (
            self.input_child_frame_override if self.input_child_frame_override
            else msg.child_frame_id
        )
        # don't copy time stamp
        # otherwise it will never find a valid transformation for some reason
        to_transform = PoseWithCovarianceStamped()
        to_transform.header.frame_id = original_frame
        to_transform.pose = msg.pose
        try:
            transformed = self.tf_buffer.transform(
                to_transform,
                target_frame,
                timeout=Duration(seconds=0.01)
            )
            msg.pose.pose = transformed.pose.pose
            msg.child_frame_id = self.output_child_frame
            return msg
        except TransformException as ex:
            self.get_logger().error(
                f'Could not transform to target frame: {ex}')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = NodeImpl()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I found some "simple logic" linked at in a related thread on the topic, but I don't feel able to apply the logic to the ROS 2 / rclpy code that I have. I would sincerely appreciate any pointers or attempts to help me solve this problem.

I think, I got this (not thoroughly tested though).
With the insights from this Q&A we can find the required adaptations of the conversion steps in Python:
def pose_to_matrix(pose):
    unpack_position = operator.attrgetter(*"xyz")
    unpack_quaternion = operator.attrgetter(*"xyzw")
    translation = unpack_position(pose.position)
    rotation = unpack_quaternion(pose.orientation)
    transform = tf_transformations.concatenate_matrices(
        tf_transformations.translation_matrix(translation),
        tf_transformations.quaternion_matrix(rotation)
    )
    return transform

def matrix_to_pose(matrix):
    translation = tf_transformations.translation_from_matrix(matrix)
    rotation = tf_transformations.quaternion_from_matrix(matrix)
    pose = Pose()
    pose.position = Point(
        **dict(zip("xyz", translation))
    )
    pose.orientation = Quaternion(
        **dict(zip("xyzw", rotation))
    )
    return pose

Then we can adjust the transformation logic to match the logic linked in the question post:
def transform_to_target(self, msg):
    target_frame = self.output_child_frame
    original_frame = (
        self.input_child_frame_override if self.input_child_frame_override
        else msg.child_frame_id
    )
    # inverse transform of local pose in global frame
    # (i.e., global frame pose in local frame)
    global_to_local = pose_to_matrix(msg.pose.pose)
    local_to_global = tf_transformations.inverse_matrix(global_to_local)
    # transform to intermediate frame
    # to acquire global pose in intermediate frame
    to_transform = PoseWithCovarianceStamped()
    to_transform.header.frame_id = original_frame
    to_transform.pose.pose = matrix_to_pose(local_to_global)
    try:
        intermediate_to_global = self.tf_buffer.transform(
            to_transform,
            target_frame,
            timeout=Duration(seconds=0.01)
        )
    except TransformException as ex:
        self.get_logger().error(
            f'Could not transform to target frame: {ex}')
        return None
    # inverse transform to find intermediate pose in global frame
    intermediate_to_global = pose_to_matrix(intermediate_to_global.pose.pose)
    global_to_intermediate = tf_transformations.inverse_matrix(intermediate_to_global)
    # return this to publish
    msg.pose.pose = matrix_to_pose(global_to_intermediate)
    msg.child_frame_id = self.output_child_frame
    return msg


Turns out, this is inefficient as hell. While receiving input at 100Hz, it was using up around 360% of CPU cores. We ended up implementing the logic with rclcpp, which was processing the same input at 7% CPU.
